# How to get method execution flow in spring mvc interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I want to get the complete execution flow along with their execution time in spring mvc project.

```
public class MetricsInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        HandlerMethod hm = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        Method method = hm.getMethod();
        if (method.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent(Controller.class)) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Metrics.class)) {
               // System.out.println(method.getAnnotation(Metrics.class).value());
                System.out.println(method.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
}
```

}

I am getting controller classes and method with @Metrics annotation to log metrics of few methods. What i want is to get entire method execution flow(Controller-->Service-->DAO) along time spent in each method. Is there anyway to get that information in postHandle() or afterCompletion(). Please suggest.

Comment: A quick hack would be to do new Exception().getStracktrace() to get the whole flow, but it will not give you the times spent

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring AOP `Around` advice this can be achieved.

Write a `pointcut` which will intercept

- All execution of public method(s) in package & its sub-packages
- And belong to packages & its sub-packages for
  - Controller layer
  - Service layer (optionally restrict to a specific service only)
  - DAO layer

Then write the *Around Advice* as below

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TraceAdvice {

    @Around("execution(* com.test..*(..))  &&" + " (within(com.test.controller..*) || "
        + "(within(com.test.service..*) && this(com.test.service.TestService)) || " + "within(com.test.dao..*))")
    public Object traceCall(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        /* This will hold our execution details in reverse order 
         * i.e. last method invoked would appear first.
         * Key = Full qualified name of method
         * Value = Execution time in ms
         */
        Map<String, Long> trace = null;
        Signature sig = pjp.getSignature();
        // Get hold of current request
        HttpServletRequest req = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        // check if we are in controller (I used RestController modify it if Controller is required instead) 
        boolean isController = sig.getDeclaringType().isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class);
        if (isController) {
            // set the request attributte if we are in controller
            trace = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            req.setAttribute("trace", trace);
        } else {
            // if its not controller then read from request atributte
            trace = (Map<String, Long>) req.getAttribute("trace");
        }
        Object result = null;
        StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
        try {
            // start the timer and invoke the advised method
            watch.start();
            result = pjp.proceed();
        } finally {
            // stop the timer 
            watch.stop();
            String methodName = sig.getDeclaringTypeName() + "." + sig.getName();
            // make entry for the method name with time taken
            trace.put(methodName, watch.getTotalTimeMillis());
            if (isController) {
                // since controller method is exit point print the execution trace
                trace.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
                    System.out.println("Method " + entry.getKey() + " took " + String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                });
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

After necessary configurations the *sample output* should look like below

> Method com.test.dao.TestDAO.getTest took 350
>   
> Method com.test.service.TestService.getTest took 1954
>   
> Method com.test.controller.TestController.getTest took 3751

*Alternatively three pointcuts and respective `Around` advice can be written each intercepting specific package so as to do away with the `if-else` part which checks the controller*

I have tested the setup with

- `Spring 4.3.2 Release`
- `AspectJ 1.7.4`
- `JDK 1.8`
- `Tomcat 8.0`

Let know in comments if there are any issues.