# How can I get flow (methods and classes being called in sequence) for a webapp in eclipse? Any plugin?

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I've a web project based on spring framework, running on tomcat server with ant as buildtool in eclipse. Is there any way by which I can trace of all the methods and classes are being called in sequence when I'm using the web application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569436/collect-all-the-method-names-in-the-flow-of-spring-mvc/42586591#42586591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Spring AOP Around advice this can be achieved.

Write a pointcut which will intercept

All execution of public method(s) in package & its sub-packages
And belong to packages & its sub-packages for
Controller layer
Service layer (optionally restrict to a specific service only)
DAO layer
Then write the Around Advice as below

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TraceAdvice {

    @Around("execution(* com.test..*(..))  &&" + " (within(com.test.controller..*) || "
        + "(within(com.test.service..*) && this(com.test.service.TestService)) || " + "within(com.test.dao..*))")
    public Object traceCall(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
... your logic
}
```

Comment: I'm a beginner with Spring framework. Unable to understand this